# How to rewrite a regexp (?<!...) in ruby1.8. (reimplement wpautop function)

Tags: ruby, regex, wordpress

I'm writing a blog archive converter in ruby. In order to convert wordpress post content to html format, I must implement wordpress's wpautop() function.

Original wpautop() function : http://pastebin.com/BzV8bXxQ

My ruby implement: https://github.com/chloerei/blog_converter/blob/master/lib/blog_converter/adaptor/wordpress.rb , see `Wordpress#wpautop_filter`

It work fine in ruby1.9.2, bu in 1.8.7, it throw an error

```
blog_converter/lib/blog_converter/adaptor/wordpress.rb:147: undefined (?...) sequence: /(?<!<br \/>)\s*\n/
```

The sources

```
// In php
$pee = preg_replace('|(?<!<br />)\s*\n|', "<br />\n", $pee); // optionally make line breaks

# In ruby
string.gsub!(%r|(?<!<br />)\s*\n|, "<br />\n") # optionally make line breaks
```

After some search, I found that ruby1.8.7 doesn't have the new regexp engine 'Oniguruma', it doesn't support new regexp syntax.

So I think I have two way:

1. Add dependent 'oniguruma' when using ruby < 1.9.0
2. Rewrite `/(?<!<br \/>)\s*\n/` in old syntax

Which way is better? And how to rewrite this regexp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If not works look-ahead assertions you can like this(attention!- not tested-i haven't 1.8):

```
string.gsub!(%r|(<br />)?\s*\n|, "<br />\n")
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this `.gsub!(%r|(<br />)?\s*\n|, "<br />\n")`